# Can we split the following limit?

Tags: calculus

▶Let us think following limit   $ R $   which is  a real number which is finite and non-zero in the region  $ 0 < \sigma < 1 $

$$ R=\lim\limits_{  x\to\infty}x^{1-2\sigma}\frac{\frac{\sin(2\sigma)}{x^{1-\sigma}}+1-\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^{1-\sigma}}{\frac{\sin(\sigma)}{x^{\sigma}}+1-\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^{\sigma}}  $$

We can not split the right side as two limits. It means:

$$ \lim\limits_{  x\to\infty}x^{1-2\sigma}\cdot \lim\limits_{  x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\sin(2\sigma)}{x^{1-\sigma}}+1-\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^{1-\sigma}}{\frac{\sin(\sigma)}{x^{\sigma}}+1-\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^{\sigma}}  $$

Because:

-- The limits in the right side;  if one is going to the zero , the other going to the infinity.

--Also, we can not apply L′Hospital rule to the second limit in the right side. Because we can not see the values of $\sin(2\sigma)$  and  $\sin(\sigma)$  as zero  in the region $0<\sigma<1$.

▶ The question: Am I right,  we can not split the right side as two limits  ?

Comment: Can someone help by  changing  it's appearance?  Thank you very much for your kind favor.

Comment: Thank very much  Jaroslaw Matlak  for your kind favor.

Comment: If both limits are finite, you can split; similarly if one is infinity and the other one is nonzero; if one is zero and the other one is infinity, you can't split.

Answer (score 9):

You can split a limit as the product of two limits provided both exist and

- both are finite, or
- both are infinite, or
- one is infinite and the other is finite and nonzero.

The case when one is zero and the other one is infinite is the well-known “indeterminate form” $0\cdot\infty$, which exactly means you cannot split the limit into the product of two limits.

I suggest to make the substitution $x=1/t$, which brings the limit to the form
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}t^{2\sigma-1}\frac{t^{1-\sigma}\sin(2\sigma)-(1-t)^{1-\sigma}}{t^\sigma\sin(\sigma)-(1-t)^\sigma}
$$
and distinguishing the cases $0<\sigma<1/2$, $\sigma=1/2$ and $1/2<\sigma<1$.

Comment: Dear Egreg  Thank you very much.  You say shortly:  If both limits are finite, we can split; similarly if one is infinity and the other one is nonzero; if one is zero and the other one is infinity, we can't split.    YES ??

Comment: @Testform Right so.

Comment: Could you please give an example for the second point where both are infinite?

Comment: @LarsSmith I'm not sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: "We can split a limit as the product of two limits provided both exist..." What does "exist" mean here? Does it mean they shouldn't be something like $\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ as $x$ approaches $0$? Because as far as I know if the limit diverges, then it does not exist but in the following sentences you mention limits that go to infinity. And another thing I would like to learn is an example that we can split a limit as the product of two limits where both is infinite. Hope it's clearer, thank you.

Comment: @LarsSmith They “exist finite or infinite”. So, for instance, $\lim_{x\to\infty}xe^x=\infty$, because both factors have limit $\infty$. To the contrary, $\lim_{x\to-\infty}xe^x$ cannot be inferred directly from the factors, because one has limit $-\infty$ and the other has limit $0$. Similarly, $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\arctan x=\infty$, because one factor has limit $\infty$ and the other has a positive finite limit.

Comment: Thank you. So we can split $\lim_{x\to\infty}xe^x$ as a product of two limits. Here, the limits diverges. What confused me first was that I thought there are two diverging limits and the product of these two limits is a real number and we can split those limits. The answer seems to be no but do we have such a case where the factors' limits go to infinity but the product's limit is a real number?

Comment: @LarsSmith No. Let's assume $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=\infty$. If $M>0$, you can find $\delta$ such that, for $0<|x-c|<\delta$ it holds both $f(x)>\sqrt{M}$ and $g(x)>\sqrt{M}$; then $f(x)g(x)>M$ and we're done to prove that $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)g(x)=\infty$. Similarly if $c$ is infinity instead of a real number.